# Can't get antd to work with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, antd

I wanted to try using ant.design with create-react-app so I followed the steps given in the antd docs.

https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app

```
npx create-react-app antd-demo
npm add antd
```

In the app.js file,

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'antd';
import './App.css';

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <Button type="primary">Button</Button>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

and in App.css

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.css';

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

...
```

When I started it, I got this error

Error: Cannot find module './locale'

▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSh8Z.jpg 
(the screenshot of the error)

So I did google it and all I found was it had something to do with moment.js which I installed too but I still continue to get the same error.

Comment: `npm add antd` -> `npm i --save antd` or using yarn `yarn add antd`

Comment: Didn't work. Same error :(

Comment: try deleting `node_modules` folder and `yarn.lock` and remove `antd` from your `package.json`, then do `yarn cache clean`. afterwards `yarn add antd-demo` and do `yarn start`. this should work. If the error persists you propaply have a wrong import in your code anywhere else

Comment: didn't work. I'm starting to think it won't. I'll stick to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the specific version of `Moment` to follow the steps.
Moment version 2.25.1 will not works. How to force 2.24.0 version using npm, not yarn, and resolutions block?

Simple trick: -

```
npm install --save-dev npm-force-resolutions
add in package.json
 "resolutions": {
    "moment": "2.24.0"
 }
```

Add to "scripts" node in package.json

```
"preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
```

Type npm install

Hope this helps.
For more details follow the Bug (https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/issues/6512) is logged in Antd Team.